# Hide/protect URL - GET string/data

Tags: php, url

How do I prevent the data string from being displayed in the URL? because anyone can quite easily overwrite what has been written and it just doesn't look tidy.

I haven't tried any Rewrite rules i figured there is a easier way.

I was under the impression that rawurlenocde and urlencode would do this but I think i'm wrong.

```
<td align="left"><a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] . '&title=' . $row['movie_title']  .'"> Read Review </a>
```

And this is how it is being displayed on the other page.

```
    <div id="sub_review_container"> <? echo ($_GET['title'])?> </div>

    <div id="Review_container"> <? echo ($_GET['id'])?> </div>
```

Comment: If you want to hide the GET parameters, the only way is URL rewriting - or not using GET.

Comment: Could I use POST in the example provided ?

Comment: Please don't recommend POST as an alternative to GET. They work differently and have different purposes, they should not generally be regarded as interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended use of POST is for things that change the state of your server: change a file, add something to a database, etc. Also, there is no easy way (that I know of) to get a browser to submit a POST request from a link (you would need to have a hidden form on your page and have the link trigger the form to be submitted). POST is also not always user friendly because if they try to refresh the page, the browser will bug them about whether or not they want to resubmit the data.

It sounds like there are two potential issues you're worried about:

1. Somebody submitting a bad value.
2. The URL does not look tidy.

For the first part, the answer is to validate the submitted values before acting on them. You should *always* do this anyway. Even with a POST, anybody with a tiny bit of know-how could submit any value they way. Any data that comes from a web client should not be trusted.

For the second part, PHP cannot solve your problem, you need to rely on the web server itself to do it. PHP only gets the data that the server sends to it, the server is the one who figures out where to route the request based on the URL. Sounds like you're using Apache httpd, so your best bet is to use URL Rewriting. It's not hard, just take an hour or less to read through the documentation and you should be able to get up and running quickly. There are other ways you could do it: convince Apache to send all requests under a certain prefix URL to your PHP script, and you can inspect the request URL from within PHP, but that's a lot more work then just using apache's Rewrite Engine.